# How to get the Font Size of Text View in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have created a `TextView` and assign its text size as `32pt`. Now i want to increase its text size on button click.

I have written following code, but i am unable to understand how to get the current size of `Text`

```
 btnIncreaseFont.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvNews.setTextScaleX(50);
        }
    });
```

Kindly guide me

Comment: use `tvNews.setTextSize(50)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
textView.setTextSize(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.textsize));
```

Sample dimensions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<dimen name="textsize">15sp</dimen>
</resources>
```